# Implement array element swap in a functional language

Tags: functional-programming, f#, immutability

Sorting algorithms involve swapping element positions in an array. This is my implementation of swap:

```
let swap (array: 'a[]) (first: int) (second: int): 'a[] = 
    let originalFirst = array.[first]
    array.[first] <- array.[second];
    array.[second] <- originalFirst;
    array
```

Though it works, I am wondering whether mutating an array is canonical F#. If not, what is the canonical way to swap array element positions?

[The F# documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/arrays) says that arrays are mutable. Am I misunderstanding immutability?

Any and all comments on the above implementation are most welcome.

Comment: If arrays were immutable, you would need to construct a new array with the elements swapped.  Mutable arrays are basically a concession to performance

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost: while mutation may be *generally* frowned upon in F#, in some cases (like this one) it's acceptable to make a tradeoff of immutability vs. performance or maintainability. In this case, it serves both of those goals.

Let's say you *want* to do this idiomatically, and you want to avoid directly mutating the array. It isn't *that* hard:

```
let swap el1 el2 arr =
    arr |> Array.mapi (fun i v ->
        match i with
        | _ when i = el1 -> arr.[el2]
        | _ when i = el2 -> arr.[el1]
        | _ -> v)
```

This uses the `mapi` function, which provides the current index *and* value (in that order, defined by the `int -> 'T -> 'U` signature) which we can then match with our `el1` (first element to swap) and `el2` (second element to swap). If we hit either of those simply return the other element.

But then, this isn't enough. What if we have several pairs to swap? We have to call `swap a1 b1 arr` then a `swap a2 b2 arr`, which could have a substantial performance penalty.

We *could* define a `swapMany` function which would take a list of tuples which are the first and second elements to swap and then handle them.

```
let swapMany els arr =
    arr |> Array.mapi (fun i v ->
        match els |> List.tryFind (fun el ->
            match el with
            | (el1, el2) when el1 = i || el2 = i -> true
            | _ -> false) with
        | Some (el1, el2) when el1 = i -> arr.[el2]
        | Some (el1, el2) when el2 = i -> arr.[el1]
        | _ -> v)
```

Now we handle all the swaps in one pass. If they're ordered, then the cost is even lower.

```
let values = [|1..10|]
let value =
    values
    |> swapMany [(4, 8); (2, 5)]
```

Result:

> ```
> [|1; 2; 6; 4; 9; 3; 7; 8; 5; 10|]
> ```

But we're still not done, let's say we want to write our `swapMany` such that it doesn't create the entire result array, we want to stream it, sort of like an `IEnumerable` in C#.

In F# this isn't nearly as hard as it seems, all we have to do here is rewrite our `swapMany` as a sequence generator, which turns it into:

```
let swapMany els arr =
    seq {
        for i in 0..(Array.length arr - 1) ->
            match els |> List.tryFind (fun el ->
                match el with
                | (el1, el2) when el1 = i || el2 = i -> true
                | _ -> false) with
            | Some (el1, el2) when el1 = i -> arr.[el2]
            | Some (el1, el2) when el2 = i -> arr.[el1]
            | _ -> arr.[i]
    }
```

Now, you might say "why would I want to write a sequence generator for an array?" Consider you have a *huge* array:

```
let values = [|1..100000000|]
```

And you want to `swapMany` on it, but you're then going to *enumerate* the array for the first 10 values:

```
let value =
    values
    |> swapMany [(4, 8); (20, 50)]
printfn "%A" (value |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.toArray)
```

You don't have to swap *everything* in the array now, you just have to swap the elements you need.

---

Second, the only issue I see with your code is the order of arguments. When writing functions it's nice to be able to use the pipe-right operator (`|>`) to push the left value as a parameter to the function on the right. In the case of your function, if I were to try to pipe an array to the right, it won't work. This is because the pipe-right (or pipe-forward) operator pipes the left side as the *last* argument to the right side.

> ```
> let swap (array: 'a[]) (first: int) (second: int): 'a[] = 
>     let originalFirst = array.[first]
>     array.[first] <- array.[second];
>     array.[second] <- originalFirst;
>     array
>
> [|1..10|] |> swap 4 5
> ```

The above code is invalid, because the argument `4` is expected to be the `'a[]` array, and the argument `5` is the `first` int, and the array `[|1..10|]` is expected to be the `second` int argument.

```
let swap (first: int) (second: int) (array: 'a[]): 'a[] = 
    let originalFirst = array.[first]
    array.[first] <- array.[second];
    array.[second] <- originalFirst;
    array

[|1..10|] |> swap 4 5
```

F# also includes a double-forward-pipe and triple-forward-pipe operator, which do the same thing but pipe a tuple of either two or three values, respectively, to the right side as the last two or three arguments, respectively.

Consider an example:

```
let append str1 str2 str3 = str1 + "." + str2 + "." + str3
printfn "%s" ("ghi" |> append "abc" "def")
printfn "%s" (("def", "ghi") ||> append "abc")
printfn "%s" (("abc", "def", "ghi") |||> append)
```

All three of the `printfn` statements will print `abc.def.ghi`.

You can see more of this looking through the framework. You'll see that most functions in `List` and `Seq` take the list or sequence as the *last* parameter, so that you can pipe the result of one function to another.

Consider how much more painful the following code would have been to write had the framework designers chosen to not take this factor into account:

> ```
> let values = [1..100]
> let value =
>     values
>     |> List.map (fun v -> Math.Sin(float v))
>     |> List.choose (fun v -> if v >= 0.0 then Some v else None)
>     |> List.rev
>     |> List.takeWhile (fun v -> v > 0.05)
>     |> List.fold (fun v acc -> acc + v) 0.0
> printfn "%f" value
> ```